# How hide FriendRequest from other users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-access-layer, subsonic2.2

I'm developing a social networking site where i'm facing problem when sending
    Friend Request from one user to another....The problem is that FriendRequest shows `` to every user not only to whom it send 
so i want to show that request to whom it send e.g: A send request to B so 
only B can see that request on FriendRequests.aspx just like facebook

I have these two pages

1. People.aspx ...
2. FriendRequests.aspx

Database table : FriendRequest.dbo

In People.aspx.....Subsonic Tool used...

```
FriendRequest obj = new FriendRequest();
obj.IsNew = true;
obj.Uid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
obj.IsFriend = false;
obj.Save();
```

In FriendRequets.aspx

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                Response.Write(Session["FID"].ToString());
                DataTable dt = Helper.ExecutePlainQuery("select * from     UserRegistration inner join Profile on UserRegistration.uid=Profile.uid inner join FriendRequest on UserRegistration.uid=FriendRequest.uid");
                repeater1.DataSource = dt;
                repeater1.DataBind();
             }
```

In database table FriendRequest.dbo

```
ReqID int primary
uid int Foreign 
isFriend bit
```

The design of these two pages just looks like facebook "People you may know" page and "Friend Requests" page

Comment: It seem you miss where condition for the query in FriendRequests.aspx. It obviously returns all the records

Answer (score 0):

Your query should looke like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM UserRegistration 
 INNER JOIN Profile on UserRegistration.uid=Profile.uid 
 INNER JOIN FriendRequest on UserRegistration.uid=FriendRequest.uid 
 WHERE ReqID= " +  obj.Uid
```

by using `WHERE` you are filtering the result to only the ones where the `ReqID` matched the logged in user. On the assumption that `ReqID` is the person `uid` wants to be friends with.

Comment: I'll take a look at this when I get home, in the meantime if you lookup 'prepared' statements, you will have some knowledge of using dynamic conditions in where clauses

Comment: You need to pass `obj.Uid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);` into `FriendRequests.aspx`, and then my answer should work.